# Importing Custom (Trumba ) RSS Feeds into Node

Tags: feeds

I'm working on a Drupal 7 college project that involve in importing the college calendar feeds into a calendar content type in Drupal. The RSS feed is coming Trumba - 25livepub-collegenet-com in the following format.

```
    <item>
        <title>Worship</title>
        <description>Christ Chapel &lt;br/&gt;Sunday, Januar</description>
        <link>http://www.gettysburg.edu/events/inde.....</link>
        <x-trumba:ealink>http://25livepub......</x-trumba:ealink>
        <category>2015/01/25 (Sun)</category>
        <pubDate>25 Jan 2015 16:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
        <guid isPermaLink="false">http://uid....8</guid>
    </item>
</channel>
```

I went to Feed Importers under Admin/Structure/Feeds and set up the Node processor as well as the Mapping for the Node processor using the following:

Source --------> Target

- Title - - > Title
- Published date - - > Published date
- Categories     ---    ---> Event Category
- Item GUID - - - -  > Item GUID
- Item URL (link) - - > URL
- Description - - - > Description

The nodes are imported into the calendar content type. The problem is everything except the **Title** is imported into the **description** field - making it difficult to differentiate them especially when the description is combine with the publish date, category etc etc. Can somebody please point me in right direction how to go about this. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [Feeds XPath Parser](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_xpathparser). Here is a quote from its project page:

> Feeds XPath Parser is a [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) plugin for parsing XML and HTML documents. It enables site builders to leverage the power of Feeds to easily import data from complex, external data sources. Each element you wish to extract is setup using configurable mapping queries, saving time for developers who would otherwise have to code complex, specific-use modules. It also enables end-users to build web scrapers and other useful tools within Drupal.